# Contact form 7 phon Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i had a job interview and they gave me to make a landing page with a validation on the phon number  that he will be between 9 to 10  numbers length and make another validation  that the phon number must start with the number "0" and all of this with  contact form 7 , some who how to do it ?

Comment: ideally you would use a regular expression, because they are compact, clean, and efficient. http://regexlib.com

Comment: I didnt understand what is that site

Comment: It is a site that can help you get started with regular expressions. It even has a library of expressions already made that you can search.

Comment: Hi ,
What is regular expration? 

I will check the site out thanks alot

Comment: it is a character matching shorthand found in most programming languages.

Comment: It is powerful and fast as long as extensions to the regular expressions aren't used.

Comment: Im new in all this web devloping thing there is any chance that can u give me an  example please im  very appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this shortcode in contact form 7 for phone number validation with length and number validation : `[tel* tel-964 minlength:9 maxlength:10]`

Comment: Yes the number length validation i already did ..  and its works thx :)

Answer (score 2):

There will be an id for the phone number field in the contact form 7 for example (phone -number)

To set max number of digits :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#phone-number").keypress(function(ev){
$("#phone-number").attr('maxlength','10');
});
</script>
```

To set 0 as 1st digit :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#phone-number").keyup(function(ev){
    var x = $(this).val();
if(x.indexOf('0')!==0){

     $('#phone-number').val('');
   }
jQuery('#phone-number').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        var x = jQuery(this).val();
        if(x.indexOf('0')!==0){
            jQuery('.val_msg').show();
        }
        else{
            jQuery('.val_msg').hide();
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Also add the following line or edit your button accordingl, example:

```
<input type="text" name="reg_phno" id="phone-number" required><span class="val_msg" style="display: none;">Please Start Your Number with 0 & maximum of 9 or 10 Numbers</span>
```

Comment: OK , i worked this out  thanks alot ! , but as i say i dont know anything about JS  and they want it to be that its will give a messege that he must enter the number "0" first and and length will be from 9 to 10 numbers , how do i do that please?

Comment: How i put a result when he try to put another number then "0" its will give a lil popup messege?